# Invalid table alias or column reference eeror in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have created a HIVE partitioned table and added a new column to one of the partition ( without the option of cascade).
I am able to see the column for the partition when i perform describe formatted  , but i am not able to read data for the newly added column.

How to access the newly added column for a partition in HIVE?

Error message below:
newly added column name is "new_name".

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:10 Invalid table alias or column reference 'new_name': (possible column names are: id, name, dob) (state=42000,code=10004)

Comment: Can you paste the query you use to create table and to add the new column.

Comment: `create table first_table(id decimal(10), name string, dob date)PARTITIONED BY (dob date);` 
Altered table using the below statement:
`alter table first_table partition ( dob='9999-12-01')  add new_name varchar(30)`

Comment: Are you sure you have used this query to create table and for adding column. The create query is wrong, it will return duplicate column error for dob as you are using it twice. Can you paste the proper query which you have used to create the table.

Comment: You are trying to change the dimension of table in one partition. I am not sure if this is a valid approach.

Comment: But Hive does allow the addition/removal of columns at partition level.
Below is the documentation from HIVE.
`ALTER TABLE table_name 
  [PARTITION partition_spec]                 -- (Note: Hive 0.14.0 and later)
  ADD|REPLACE COLUMNS (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)
  [CASCADE|RESTRICT]                         -- (Note: Hive 1.1.0 and later)`
If that is valid, why am I not able to access the column that is newly added.

Comment: Add/Replace Columns
    ALTER TABLE table_name 
      [PARTITION partition_spec]                 -- (Note: Hive 0.14.0 and later)
      ADD|REPLACE COLUMNS (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)
      [CASCADE|RESTRICT] in this there are two commands one is replace and another is add. from my understanding. the partition partition spec is for replace not for add even the cascade and the restrict also are for replace not for add. you can add column before the partition column. you can not change the schema of one partition.